# NEXTJS pass to hook props and receive redux action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I'm have a page what render a componenet and send to they a prop, also that component receive a redux action.

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ComponentReceiver new="yes" />
  )
}


export default function ComponentReceiver({reduxAction}, props) {
  return (
    <h1>{props.new}</h1>
  )
}
```

this not work,props.new is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component will always receive props. Redux actions are passed along as props.

So you have two options here. You can either destructure your component props:

```
export default function ComponentReceiver({reduxAction, new}) {
  return (
    <h1>{new}</h1>
  )
}
```

Note that you will have to rename `new` as it’s a reserved keyword.

Or don’t destruct, let it be just `props`, and use props.new and props.reduxAction in your component.